# ROS: bag file buffer burst

Tags: c++, buffer, ros, rosbag

I am using rosbag's API: write to write messages from one bag to another, but when I run the code, an error occurs:

**

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'ros::serialization::StreamOverrunException' what(): Buffer Overrun

**

I think the buffer of the bag file burst, so I want to ask how to increase the buffer size of the bag file in the code.

Comment: More info is needed to answer this question. What code specifically causes the above error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.